# Counting number of objects within a field of mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

```
console.log(game.gameQuestions);
```

The above code outputs:

```
 [Object, Object, Object].
```

I would like to somehow count the number of objects.  When I try

```
console.log(game.gameQuestions.count());
```

The console outputs :

```
Exception from Deps recompute function: TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Additionally if I try:

```
console.log(game.gameQuestions.length());
```

The console outputs :

```
Exception from Deps recompute function: TypeError: number is not a function
```

How do I count the number of objects within an attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fetched document from mongodb is just a JavaScript object without any magic applied. `game.gameQuestions` is an array, so it will have a [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property. Length is a positive integer, which explains your last error. This should work:

```
console.log(game.gameQuestions.length);
```